# What is a possibility of rolling two dice and the result of the rolling will be exactly 1 and 5

Tags: probability, dice

I was learning about probability and how does probability works with events and elementary events. So from my understanding, if we throw two dice there are 36 possible results (6 from the one die and 6 from the another), and 2 events that we want to see (1 and 5), so the result should be 2(events that we want to see) / 36 (possible results) = 0.055.

I want to be sure if I'm correct and if I'm wrong please correct me and tell me what is wrong.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes,that is basically correct.

Comment: "Dice" is plural.  The singular is "die."  We "throw two dice."  $\frac{2}{36} = \frac{1}{18} = 0.0555555555555555\cdots = 0.0\overline{5} \neq 0.055 = \frac{55}{1000}$.  Otherwise, this is fine.

Comment: What are the two events you counted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ where $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2$ is the sample space, whose elements we call *outcomes*, $\mathcal F = \mathcal P(\Omega)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of *events* (note that $\mathcal F$ can only be defined this way if $\Omega$ is finite or countably infinite), and $\mathbb P$ is a map from $\mathcal F$ to $\mathbb R$ defined by $\mathbb P(E) = \frac{|E|}{|\Omega|}$, where $|\cdot|$ denotes the cardinality of a set. Note that the probability measure can only be defined this way if $\Omega$ is finite, as clearly division by infinity is not well-defined.

Here we are interested in the probability of the event consisting of the outcomes $(1,5)$ and $(5,1)$ - so let $E=\{(1,5),(5,1)\}$. Then
$$
\mathbb P(E) = \frac{|E|}{|\Omega|} = \frac 2{36} = \frac1{18}.
$$